# Circuitikz: increase the distance of a resistor label

Tags: labels, circuitikz

In such a simple circuit

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

Resistance:

\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) to [R=$R$,*-*,v=$V_1 - V_2$] (2,0);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

I would like to increase the distance between the label (so, the arrow and the $V_1 - V_2$ expression) and the resistor itself.

1) Hoping that it is possible, how can I do it?

2) Again, if possible, how can the arrow be bent a little bit more? If I change the scale to, say, 2.0, the arrow line appears almost straight.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen Ok, I tried to include the code you suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `voltage/bump b` and `voltage/european label distance` parameters to do what you want:

```
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,2) to [R=$R$,*-*,v=$V_1 - V_2$] (2,2);
\ctikzset{voltage/bump b=20pt,voltage/european label distance=15pt}
\draw (0,0) to [R=$R$,*-*,v=$V_1 - V_2$] (2,0);
\end{circuitikz}
```

[image: rendering]

Comment: This does not seem to work anymore (Tex Live 2018).

Comment: @FlorianL That's true indeed. As far as I can tell circuitikz is now broken (or the documentation is not up to date), and has no backward compatibility at all.